# TypeError: e is null error

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova

I am currently trying to put the results of an AJAX GET request into a table for an app under development in PhoneGap. However I keep receiving the error below and can't seen to figure out why.

> TypeError: e is null

The result of the ajax is as follows:

```
[{ 
    name: "test1"
},{ 
    name: "test2"
}]
```

The code going with it is:

```js
function getMatches() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'url',
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
            var jsonObj = $.parseJSON(result);
            var html = '<table>';
            $.each(jsonObj, function(key, value){
                html += '<tr>';
                html += '<td>' + key + '</td>';
                html += '<td>' + value + '</td>';
                html += '</tr>';
            });
            html += '</table>';
            $( "div#results" ).replaceWith(html);
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log(result);
            alert('There was an error making getting your offers');
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I think u don't need $.parseJSON

Comment: You seem to be right, at least I am getting output. However it is shown as:
0 [object Object]
1 [object Object]

What am I missing?

Comment: right u getting JSON object. if u convert it in String use JSON.stringify(jsonObj )

Comment: use **html += '<td>' + value.name + '</td>';**

Comment: Never mind, got it! Thanks

Comment: Also make sure to pass something to your error handler, it will throw as it stands now. `error: function(err){
            console.log(err);
            alert('There was an error making getting your offers');
        }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  getMatches();
  function getMatches() {
      $.ajax({
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: "json",
          url: 'url',
          success: function(result){
              console.log(result);
              var jsonObj = result;
              var html = '<table>';
              $.each(jsonObj, function(key, value){
                  html += '<tr>';
                  html += '<td>' + key + '</td>';
                  html += '<td>' + value.name + '</td>';
                  html += '</tr>';
              });
              html += '</table>';
              $( "div#results" ).replaceWith(html);
          },
          error: function(){
              console.log(result);
              alert('There was an error making getting your offers');
          }
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the next newbie ... another scenario of how this error popped up.

I solved this error by just using single quotes in the function's argument.

Code:

```
// in your .js file
function showhidediv(id) { 

   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   e.style.display = (e.style.display == 'block') ? 'none' : 'block';

}

// In the HTML File
<button type="button"  onclick="showhidediv('busydates')"> Show/Hide Busy Dates <button>

<div id="busydates" style="display:none;">
      <p>This div will show and hide content on the above button click </p>
</div>
```

Without the single quotes at onclick="showhidediv('busydates'), TypeError: e is null pops up.